# Rack Mount for a 3Com 4210 switch

Tags: hardware, switch, rackmount

Does anyone know where I can get a rack mount kit for a 3Com 4210 9 port switch. Needs to fit into a 19" rack

Comment: http://www.pcconnectionexpress.com/1/1/3170236-3com-rack-mount-kit-switch-4210-9-18-port-2150a026.html

Comment: You should at least mention your country...

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to find a rack kit for that switch, however searching for "rack mount shelves" will give you plenty of options.